# How to show/get a link/shortcut in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

In PowerShell, I type:

```
PS C:\Users\user01\Desktop> ls -force
```

This shows 8 files, but 2 are hidden (Mode: `-a-hs`). So the command tells me that I have 6 files.

But when I look at the Desktop, I see 9 files. I know that 3 of them are links/shortcuts (including Recycle Bin).

How can I make PowersSell show all the files/shortcuts?
Or is a link/shortcut not a file/item?

Comment: try -include *.lnk

Comment: Not working.
How links are diferent from Application files?

Comment: works for me in the powershell ISE - running as Administrator

Comment: I am unable to replicate this issue it works fine for me. What version of powershell and what operating system?

Comment: Recycle Bin is part of shell namespace, but not part of file system.

Comment: Yeah, some things are shell icons, also consider that some icons may be on the all users desktop, not your specific desktop. Not a common practice anymore, but it happens.

Comment: In addition to Recycle Bin, up to four other shell items (but not files) may appear on the desktop:  Computer, Control Pannel, Network, Users's Files.   These can be renamed, as their actual identity is a GUID.   While technically possible, iterating these in PowerShell would be a lot of work.

Comment: Not as hard as I thought...

Answer (score 0):

Here's script returning shell `FolderItem` objects for all items the desktop:

```
$shell = new-object -com shell.application
$desktop = $shell.Namespace(0)
$desktop.Items()
```

Comment: It will show all shell objects, though, regardless of whether they're displayed or not.